# Django. Check if its another day

Tags: python, django, datefield

How can I check that, there is another day from my date variable? I mean, how to write if statement between my DateField, and actuall date to check is is another day (for example: last was 26 July, now is 27, so i want to show alert box).

Comment: Show some input and desired output.

Comment: Can you specify where exactly you are trying to match the Datefield ? Is it in HTML page or in views.py ? Need few more details like from where you are fetching the datefield

Comment: I want add free points to user every day he log in. No mather what time is it, its giving points every day, so I need condition which will check is it another day, from his "last_points_added" datefield.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def some_view(request):
    now = datetime.now()
    # using a timedelta avoids having to know about length of months etc:
    same_time_tomorrow = now + timedelta(days=1)
    start_of_tomorrow = same_time_tomorrow.replace(
        hour=0,
        minute=0,
        second=0,
        microsecond=0
    )
    # returns a timedelta object:
    difference = start_of_tomorrow - request.user.last_points_added
    if difference.days > 0:
        # add points
```